# How to import a class from another file which is importing first class for

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hello I want to import a class from another class.

My file structure is the following:

```
Project
│
├─ folder1/
│   └─ file1.py
│
└─ folder2
     └─ file2.py
```

---

**`file1.py`**

```
from folder2.file2 import B

class A:
  """some things"""
```

**`file2.py`**

```
from folder1.file1 import A

class B:
  """something"""

class C(A):
   """something"""
```

---

When I run `file1.py` It says:

> File "./folder1/file1.py", line 1, in  `from folder2.file2 import B`
>
> File "./folder2/models.py", line 1, in  `from folder1.models import A`
>
> ImportError: cannot import name `A`

Comment: if you need it for models FK you can use string `app.ModelName` other case read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226016/simple-cross-import-in-python

Comment: @BearBrown I did't knew this condition was called Cross import. So, I could not search this solution.