# How to import from project level package in Django without conflicting with app level module with same name?

Tags: python, django, python-import, python-2.x

I have a Django project (Python 2.7.15) with the following structure:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
        utils.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        filters.py
```

In my `utils/filters.py` file I have a class `MyFilter`. From `polls/admin.py`, however, when I try to run `from utils.filters import MyFilter`, I get `ImportError: No module named filters`. How can I import my custom filter inside the polls app without renaming the `polls/utils.py` module or the `utils` package?

NOTE: This it's not a circular import problem. This happens even if I don't import anything from `utils/filters.py`. It's a name conflict between `utils/` and `polls/utils.py`. Python tries to find `filters.MyFilter` inside `polls/utils.py` and it doesn't find it so it throws the error. I just want to figure out a way to bypass this conflict and force python to look for `filters.MyFilter` inside the `utils/` package in the project root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple cross import in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226016/simple-cross-import-in-python)

Comment: @BearBrown it's not a circular import problem. This happens even if I don't import anything from `utils/filters.py`. It's a name conflict between `utils/` and `polls/utils.py`. Python tries to find `filters.MyFilter` inside `polls/utils.py` and it doesn't so it throws the error. I just want to figure out a way to bypass this conflict and force python to look for `filters.MyFilter` inside the `utils/` package in the project root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `import utils` is ambiguous because it can be a relative or an absolute import.

If you enable the Python 3 behaviour by adding the following import to the top of your module,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

then `from utils.filters import MyFilter` will be treated as an absolute import and will work.

Once you have added the future import, you would need to use an explicit relative import `import .utils` if you wanted to import `polls/utils.py` from `polls/admin.py`.

Comment: That did it. I forgot to mention I was using Python 2, my bad. I updated the body of the question to also mention that. Thanks!

Comment: Weirdly enough, this caused errors elsewhere in the project where there were relative imports (with dots) `RuntimeError: Model class 'foo.models.Bar' doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`. Changing `from .models import Bar` to `from myapp.models import Bar` fixed the issue. This seems totally mysterious to me I don't understand how it is possible, but I guess that's a topic for another question.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that belongs on another question, and would require more information to explain what was going on.