# 'spaceship' class is not defined (even though I've imported it?)

Tags: python-3.x

I run the main module, which should work correctly. But an error gets returned. 'spaceship' is not defined when I define 's=spaceship(parameters)' why is this I don't get it. I'm using zelle graphics for python. thank you

Functions from main module:

## spaceshipGame file

```
 from graphics import *
    from spaceshipClass import *

def main():
    window=createGraphicsWindow()
    runGame(window)
    
    
def createGraphicsWindow():
    win=GraphWin("Spaceship game",800,800)
    return win
    
    
def createSpaceship(window,p1,p2,p3,speed,colour):
    s=spaceship(window,p1,p2,p3,speed,colour)
    return s
    
    
    
def runGame(window):
    player=createSpaceship(window,Point(500,500),Point(500,470),Point(520,485),0.5,"red")
    player.draw(window)
    
main()
```

## spaceshipClass file

```
    from spaceshipGame import *
from graphics import *
class spaceship:
    def __init__(self,window,p1,p2,p3,speed,colour):
        self.p1=p1
        self.p2=p2
        self.p3=p3
        self.speed=speed
        self.colour=colour
        self.window=window
```

Comment: Where is `window` in `__init__`?

Comment: @IFunball still says 'spaceship' is not defined, but good thing you pointed it out

Comment: @IFunball  The indentation isn't actually happening in my code it's just the way I've written it here. Well that's just odd. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'll rewrite the whole thing in other files and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I see the problem. Consult this example for more information:

[Simple cross import in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226016/simple-cross-import-in-python)

But the problem is the way you are cross importing, so delete `from spaceshipGame import *` from `spaceshipClass` or vise-versa (i.e. delete `from spaceshipClass import *` from `spaceshipGame`). You can import individually if you need to like in the example I provided.

There are also many other ways around it if you read the example. One of the easiest would be just merging them in the same file if they need to share a lot of methods.