# solve import conflict when modifying variable from the argument of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

The following is simplified code for better understanding. There are two modules,

The first:

```
from modulo2 import f1

f = [f1 + 4, f1 + 2]
def first():
    print(f[0])

def second():
     print(f[1])
```

The second:

```
from modulo1 import first, second

f1 = 0
def main_function(f1):
    first()
    second()

main_function(5)
main_function(10)
#
#etc
```

It is a case of circular import, and what I want is that when executing `main_function(f1)` the variable `f1` is modified in the first module according to the given argument.

I have tried many ways without success, I always get an error on import.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'first'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is massive code smell. The best design will have modules that are modular: self-contained in terms of the resources they use. Using global variables prevents effective modularity.

Additionally, when you define a list, the elements are evaluated once. For example, the expression `f1 + 4` is only evaluated once, even if you were to successfully define `f1` in `modulo1`.

You can solve both problems by passing your data around and using additional functions to define dynamic behavior.

```
def f(f1):
    return [f1 + 4, f1 + 2]

def first(f1):
     print(f(f1)[0])

def second(f1):
     print(f(f1)[1])
```

Notice that `modulo1` does not refer to `modulo2` at all in this incarnation, but presents the same functionality as before. You can simplify it further:

```
def first(f1):
     print(f(f1 + 4))

def second(f1):
     print(f(f1 + 2))
```

Now your imports will work:

```
from modulo1 import first, second

def main_function (f1):
    first(f1)
    second(f1)

main_function(5)
main_function(10)
#
#etc
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226016/simple-cross-import-in-python) in stackoverflow itself. Based on this, in order to solve your cross import there are few changes that are needed.

first file, lets say modulo1.py

```
f=[] # creating a empty list

def start():
    from modulo2 import f1 # import the cross module inside a function rather than in the top
    global f # using the global "f", so assigned values will be same through out the program
    f = [f1 + 4, f1 + 2] # adding values to list "f"

def first():
     print (f[0])

def second ():
     print (f[1])
```

second file, lets say modulo2.py

```
from modulo1 import start, first, second

f1 = 0
def main_function(f1):
     start() # this is called to create the list "f" in modulo1.py
     first()
     second()

def main():
    main_function(5)
    main_function(10)


if __name__ == "__main__": # this will make sure main_fucntions will only run once as we are doing cross import
    main()
```

Comment: That looks pretty terrible. Instead of having one difficult to understand piece of code that the interpreter actually complains about, you now have a whole bunch of bad code to obscure the problem